# Is it possible to connect bluetooth low energy OBDII devices to iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, btle, elm327

I want to develop an app that allows me to connect Bluetooth 4.0 OBDII to an iPhone and read car data from it. From what I've read so far, it's not supported, but the OBDII adapters [here](https://www.amazon.ca/iKKEGOL-Bluetooth-Diagnostic-Scanner-Analyzer/dp/B016F6FGEM/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1467228797&sr=8-2&keywords=viecar) and [here](https://www.amazon.ca/Carista-Bluetooth-Adapter-Scanner-Android/dp/B00YVHGTBM/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1467228280&sr=8-5&keywords=ELM327+ios+bluetooth) both support iOS. How is this possible?

Comment: Did you get any feasible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth 4.0 devices have been supported since iOS 6 which was released in 2012. Since then, a multitude of apps have been written that communicate via BLE.